# Couldn't draw shapes on the map using leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I am using javascript library leaflet to deal with map, I did the location searching part now I want that user can draw circle, line and polygon on the map but the could is not working. The toolbar of searching is visible but of the shapes is not. Can any one point out eh mistake in my code, Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

  <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet"></script>

  <!-- Esri Leaflet Geocoder -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/leaflet-draw-toolbar/dist/leaflet.draw-toolbar.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!----    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar-src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src.js"></script>--!-->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"> </div>
  <script>
    var center = [-33.8650, 151.2094];

    var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 6);
    drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=eL1sdTPWF7XeyxpLvpGq', {

      attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'

    }).addTo(map);

    var searchContrl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch().addTo(map);

    //adding layergroup to search control

    var results = L.layerGroup.addTo(map);

    searchContrl.on('results', function(data) {
      results.clearLayers();
      for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlong));
      }
    });

    var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(editableLayers);

    var MyCustomMarker = L.Icon.extend({
      options: {
        shadowUrl: null,
        iconAnchor: new L.Point(12, 12),
        iconSize: new L.Point(24, 24),
        iconUrl: 'link/to/image.png'
      }
    });

    var options = {
      position: 'topright',
      draw: {
        polyline: {
          shapeOptions: {
            color: '#f357a1',
            weight: 10
          }
        },
        polygon: {
          allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
          drawError: {
            color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
            message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
          },
          shapeOptions: {
            color: '#bada55'
          }
        },
        circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
        rectangle: {
          shapeOptions: {
            clickable: false
          }
        },
        marker: {
          icon: new MyCustomMarker()
        }
      },
      edit: {
        featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
        remove: false
      }
    };

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(options);
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
      var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

      if (type === 'marker') {
        layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
      }

      editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use is wrong

```
var results = L.layerGroup.addTo(map);
```

should be

```
var results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);
```

(Like you did in the search container)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

  <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet"></script>

  <!-- Esri Leaflet Geocoder -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/leaflet-draw-toolbar/dist/leaflet.draw-toolbar.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!----    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar-src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src.js"></script>--!-->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"> </div>
  <script>
    var center = [-33.8650, 151.2094];

    var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 6);
    drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=eL1sdTPWF7XeyxpLvpGq', {

      attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'

    }).addTo(map);

    var searchContrl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch().addTo(map);

    //adding layergroup to search control
    console.log(L.LayerGroup);
    var results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

    searchContrl.on('results', function(data) {
      results.clearLayers();
      for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlong));
      }
    });

    var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(editableLayers);

    var MyCustomMarker = L.Icon.extend({
      options: {
        shadowUrl: null,
        iconAnchor: new L.Point(12, 12),
        iconSize: new L.Point(24, 24),
        iconUrl: 'link/to/image.png'
      }
    });

    var options = {
      position: 'topright',
      draw: {
        polyline: {
          shapeOptions: {
            color: '#f357a1',
            weight: 10
          }
        },
        polygon: {
          allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
          drawError: {
            color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
            message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
          },
          shapeOptions: {
            color: '#bada55'
          }
        },
        circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
        rectangle: {
          shapeOptions: {
            clickable: false
          }
        },
        marker: {
          icon: new MyCustomMarker()
        }
      },
      edit: {
        featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
        remove: false
      }
    };

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(options);
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
      var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

      if (type === 'marker') {
        layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
      }

      editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

BTW, I used `var` because of your syntax but `const` and `let` are much better.

Comment: It don't have to be `new L.LayerGroup()`, `L.layerGroup()` is also working.

Comment: Tried that. It gives `Uncaught TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function
    at Object.NewClass [as LayerGroup]`

Comment: You have to call it without `new`: `var group = L.layerGroup()` like in the [Doc](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/)